# Activador que no logro que funcione

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando lograr, que cuando un usuario digite el número 1 en un registro de la columna H, ese registro se agregue al final de otra hoja de otro libro. Asocié la función con el activador "Al hacer cambios" en una hoja de cálculo.

```js
function onFormChange(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('TOTAL');

  //var reporteMinId = "ID_DEL_REPORTE_MIN";
  var reporteMin = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID_DEL_REPORTE_MIN);

  // Obtener la hoja destino del libro "REPORTE_MIN"
  var fase1Sheet = reporteMin.getSheetByName('prueba');

  // Verificar si hay un rango y si el cambio ocurrió en la columna "Caracterización" (columna H)
  if (e.range && e.range.getColumn() == 8 && e.range.getValue() == 1) {
    // Obtener los datos del registro
    Logger.log("h")
    var rowData = sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    Logger.log(rowData)

    // Agregar el registro a la hoja destino
    fase1Sheet.appendRow(rowData);

  }
}
```

He puesto los Logger para ver que pasa y he podido establecer que no logra entrar al if de la función.  Alguien puede darme una mano con esto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un problema con el formato de la celda debes asegurarte que sea de tipo numérico, de hecho puedes cambiar la condición a tipo texto "8" o "1" para verificar.

Asi sería la condición de tipo texto:

```vb
if (e.range && e.range.getColumn() == "8" && e.range.getValue() == "1") {
    // Obtener los datos del registro
    Logger.log("h")
    var rowData = sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    Logger.log(rowData)

    // Agregar el registro a la hoja destino
    fase1Sheet.appendRow(rowData);

  }
```